# Taking input from a file and performing addition using bash command

Tags: bash, unix, text-files

I was trying to get an input from  a file and performing arithmetic operation

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=menu.txt
IFS=","
[ ! -f $INPUT ] &while read ch ch1 menu rate quantity 
do
echo "Choice : $ch"
echo "Choice of menu : $ch1"
echo "menu : $menu"
echo "price : $rate"
echo "quantity : $quantity"
echo "$(($rate * $quantity))" 
done < $INPUT
```

while executing this code It throws an error

> Choice : veg
>       Choice of menu : soup
>       menu : corn soup
>       price : 160
>       quantity : 1
>       ")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "

Can anyone help me in solving this?

Comment: use command substitution "`" like

Comment: can you be more clear in writing the whole syntax am not getting it what u mean

Answer (score 0):

The is most likely to be because of floating point arithmetic. I am assuming that the `rate` variable is a floating point number. Thus you need this:

```
echo "$rate * $quantity" | bc
```

Comment: in the last variable quantity the enter button which i pressed also stored.how to remove that

Comment: It ideally won't, it may look like it because you're using echo and not printf

Answer (score 0):

From that inside-out error message, I'd guess that your menu.txt file is in DOS/Windows format, meaning that each line ends with a carriage return and linefeed. Unix tools like bash expect lines to end with just a linefeed (the unix format for text files), and therefore treat the carriage return character as part of the line. In your script, that means the variable `quantity` has a number *and a carriage return* in it, and the carriage return means it's not a valid number, and causes the error.

There are several ways to fix this. You can run `dos2unix` (or a similar program) on the menu.txt file. Alternately, you can also make the script trim the carriage return; one way to do that is to add carriage return to `IFS`, so the `read` command will treat it as whitespace and trim it. BTW, it'd be best to do this (and the assignment of "," to IFS) as a prefix to the `read` command so they *only* apply to that command and won't mess things up in other places:

```
[ ! -f $INPUT ] &while IFS=$',\r' read ch ch1 menu rate quantity
```

Also, that test looks backward to me. Do you really want to run the loop if the input file *doesn't* exist? That usage of `&` makes it hard to read; it'd be better to use an explicit `if` (and double-quote the variable reference), like this:

```
if [ -f "$INPUT" ]; then
    while IFS=$',\r' read ch ch1 menu rate quantity; do
        ...
```